# Filter ListView results from an EditText

Tags: android, android-listview, filter, android-edittext, xamarin

In Xamarin, I have an EditText and a ListView with a Custom adapter.

Here is my code:

```
inputSearch = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.inputSearch);
listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.List);
listView.Adapter = new MapLocationDetailsActivityAdapter(this, tableItems);
```

Here is my adapter code:

```
public class MapLocationDetailsActivityAdapter : BaseAdapter<MapLocationDetailsActivityListViewTableItem> {
    List<MapLocationDetailsActivityListViewTableItem> items;
    Activity context;
    public MapLocationDetailsActivityAdapter(Activity context, List<MapLocationDetailsActivityListViewTableItem> items)
        : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override MapLocationDetailsActivityListViewTableItem this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = items[position];

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomView, null);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TextViewMapHeading).Text = item.Heading;
        view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.TextViewMapHeading).TextSize = 20;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TextViewItem).Text = item.SubHeading;
        view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Image).SetImageResource(item.ImageResourceId);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is my ListView item code:

```
public class MapLocationDetailsActivityListViewTableItem 
{
    public string Heading { get; set; }
    public string SubHeading { get; set; }
    public int ImageResourceId { get; set; }
}
```

How can I filter the ListView results when I type text into the EditText?

I wish to filter the item.Heading value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw you were creating the list adapter from an object called "tableItems" - assuming that's a `List<MapLocationDetailsActivityListViewTableItem>` , this should work :

```
inputSearch.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    listView.Adapter = new MapLocationDetailsActivityAdapter
    (
        this,
        tableItems.Where(item => item.Heading.StartsWith(inputSearch.Text)).ToList()
    );
};
```

The idea you should start from is that you first have to filter your list and then create a new list adapter from it .